# yii-booster set up giving me errors

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Sorry real new to yii, but where do i put the [yii-booster 2.0](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/index.html) files?

I tried putting all the files into the **extensions/bootstrap** folder.

I then edited **config/main.php** and added this

```
'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
),
```

and

```
'preload'=>array(
          'log',
         // 'fontawesome',
         'bootstrap',
    ),
```

and

```
'theme'=>'bootstrap',
```

where I have a theme in **themes/bootstrap** which I took from my previous installation of http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/

but I'm getting this error

```
Bootstrap and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "register".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the theme you got from http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/

try removing this in **themes/bootstrap/views/layout/main.php**

```
Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
```